# the below code input o1ps will return oops but o2ps should return ooops is there any way we can execute o2ps has ooops

Tags: java

```
package adc;
import java.util.*;
public class bca {
public static void main(String[] args)
{
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the sentence to decrypt");
String s=sc.nextLine();
char[] ans = s.toCharArray();
int len=s.length();
char[] sol= new char[len];
System.out.println("len="+s.length());
for(int i=0;i<len;i++) {
    int j=i;
    if(ans[i]=='1') {
        sol[i]=ans[i-1];
    }
    else if(ans[i]=='2') {
        sol[i]=ans[i-1];
        sol[i+1]=ans[i-1];
        
        
    }
    else {
        sol[i]=ans[i];
    }
    System.out.print(sol[i]);
    }
  sc.close();
    
  }
  }
```

> new here learning java tring to get some help here thank you.

**Enter the sentence to decrypt
Input:o1ps o2ps
output:len=9
oops oops***is it possible to make o2ps has ooops*

Comment: Yes.  You cannot use i for both sol and ans.

Answer (score 2):

You need different counters for the input string and the output string, however, as you don't know in advance the length of the output string, you can use a `StringBuilder`:

```
    char[] ans = s.toCharArray();
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
    System.out.println("len=" + s.length());
    for (int i = 0; i < ans.length; i++) {
        if (i > 0 && ans[i] >= '0' && ans[i] <= '9') {
            char prev = ans[i-1];
            int count = ans[i] - '0';
            for (int j = 0; j < count; ++j) {
                out.append(prev);
            }
        } else {
            out.append(ans[i]);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("output=" + out);
```

UPDATE:

To also reverse words:

```
    char[] ans = s.toCharArray();
    List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
    System.out.println("len=" + s.length());
    for (int i = 0; i < ans.length; i++) {
        if (ans[i] == ' ') {
            if (out.length() > 0) {
                words.add(out.toString());
                out.setLength(0);
            }
        } else if (i > 0 && ans[i] >= '0' && ans[i] <= '9') {
            char prev = ans[i-1];
            int count = ans[i] - '0';
            for (int j = 0; j < count; ++j) {
                out.append(prev);
            }
        } else {
            out.append(ans[i]);
        }
    }
    if (out.length() > 0) {
        words.add(out.toString());
    }
    Collections.reverse(words);
    String output = words.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
    System.out.println("output=" + output);
```

Comment: Thanks sir.it helped me a lot.

Comment: sir but i need to reverse the words has hel1o go2d has goood hello is this possible using string builder

Comment: @AbcdDcba yes, but it's a little more complicated.

Comment: @AbcdDcba see my UPDATE in the post.

Comment: Thanks sir its working fine but can you pls explain how this line works. String output = words.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(" "));

Comment: @AbcdDcba int joins all the words in list `words` into a string with `" "` as a delimiter between words. You could do this without using streams, but it's much simpler that way.

Comment: Thanks i am new to java practicing with some of web site like hackerrack do you know some webside where i can practice java to make my logic in java strong.

Comment: *"it helped me a lot"* The best way to indicate that is to click the 'tick' on the left of the question. Please also revisit your other earlier questions and do the same thing for any answer that helped.